# Error in parsing String to JSON

Tags: android, json

I get error:

```
Value {message: { parent_id:0, to:31, topic:Test message3333222, content:frf}} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.
```

I create this like that:

```
return "{message: { parent_id:"
+getParent_id()+", to:"
+getTo()+", topic:"
+getTopic()+", content:"
+getContent()+"}}";
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Vote for close with "unclear what's being asked"? Really???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON key is String, so it should has quotation mark, that is the key `message` should be `"message"`.

Instead of creating JSON String yourself, you should use code like this:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
jObj.putString("key", "value");
jObj.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

write it like this

```
return "{\"message\": { \"parent_id\":\""
            +getParent_id()+"\", \"to\":\""
            +getTo()+"\", \"topic\":\""
            +getTopic()+"\", \"content\":\""
            +getContent()+"\"}}";
```

json string, object and key must be in between " "